# Flutter not installing properly for Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, command-prompt

So I am tryin to download flutter on android studio. I downloaded the plugin for it and it shows up on android studio when I look for it but when I run

```
flutter doctor
```

it says

```
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
```

I don't know what the problem is because I have the plugin installed on android studio but flutter can't find it. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you download flutter sdk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known bug that u can ignore and it doesn't affect you as long as u have the plugins installed. For more info check [This issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67986)

Answer (score 0):

The error will disappear just after running it once. Try running it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
[image]

check your Dart SDK path correctly, after this apply.
may this helpful for you.